# Grinding vs Pulverizing

Tags: meaning, word-usage

What are the differences between *grinding* vs *pulverizing* in terms of reducing the size of nuts or seeds? Which one makes finer particles? Thank you.

grind

- To reduce to small bits or crush to a fine powder
- To become crushed, pulverized, or powdered by friction

pulverize

- To pound, crush, or grind to a powder or dust
- To be ground or reduced to powder or dust

(American Heritage Dictionary)

Comment: Grinding and pulverising mean the same thing. If accuracy is desired, particle size is specified.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey *Grinding and pulverising mean the same thing.* This is not so at all! To grind = to reduce by abrasion or compression; to pulverise = to reduce to power, "He ground the knife blade until it was sharp" -- "He pulverised the knife blade."

Comment: I drink something prepared from what Marks and Spencer call "ground coffee".

Comment: @Greybeard - Have you ever seen the metal dust or powder that results from grinding?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - *I drink something prepared from what Marks and Spencer call "ground coffee".* As opposed to coffee powder/powdered coffee? The grinding results in pulverisation. The pulverising is done by grinding. Pulverising can be done by various methods - percussion. explosion, etc.

Comment: Grinding your teeth is not the same as pulverising your teeth.

Answer (score 2):

If you 'pound' something you strike it repeatedly, for instance by hitting it with a hammer or a club. A stamping machine could also 'pound' something. If you 'grind' something, on the other hand, you apply fairly consistent pressure to the grinding tool and move it in such a way that the tool wears down the substance to be ground. Mill wheels 'grind' as does a pestle in a pestle and mortar.

The definitions of "pulverise" that you give include both "grind" and "pound". This shows that "grinding" and "pounding" are different processes which can contribute to the process of "pulverising" something so "pulverise" is a more general term incorporating both of the others. "Crushing" is another term which can include both "grinding" and "pounding" but can also include "squeezing' which means that it is not a true synonym of "pulverising".

Comment: how would you characterise the action of a ball mill?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I haven't come across a ball mill but I imagine that its action would be similar to a roller mill except that the feedstock would sit in a channel whose section has a diameter very similar to that of the ball. The ball will apply more or less constant pressure as it rolls around the channel so it doesn't **pound** but won't keep working on the same feedstock for long so does not **grind**. If I understand a ball mill correctly it will, primarily, **crush** the feedstock. In other words it will **pulverise** by crushing. That's similar to what happens to grapes and olives.

Comment: The common feature of all processes that result in pulverisation is, surely, the application of pressure, whether by the teeth of a file, grinding wheel, etc, or by crushing, striking blows, etc.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That is true but when you **pound** something you apply the pressure as repeated blows removing the pressure between them; when you **crush** something you apply either a single blow or a sustained pressure to it; when you **grind** something you apply sustained pressure but with movement over the same sample of the substance you are grinding. In each case you are **pulverising** the substance but the processes are different. Some processes use combinations of those processes but they are distinct. Crushing and pounding can also be used when the object is not pulverised.

Comment: A typical ball mill will be a steel cylinder containing a number of steel, iron, ceramic, etc balls, which are free to tumble as the cylinder is rotated. Material placed in the cylinder is reduced to powder after a time.

Comment: Thank you so much all for your responses. I later found that it was rather a question of **milling** and **grinding** in the context of nuts and seeds. Can I understand that grinding makes them finer than milling?

Comment: @dolph - you cannot assume that any particular pulverisation process makes finer particles than any other.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - If both milling and grinding are part of the process, can you tell which one likely comes first?

Comment: That is more an engineering question.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Given your description I would describe the action of a ball mill as **pounding** since the pulverising  action is intermittent and dependent mainly on the random action of falling balls. There is certainly no consistent pressure applied.

Comment: @dolph I would imagine that the **milling** in this context involves **crushing** the nuts and seeds between rollers, or possibly **pounding** them in a ball mill as described by Michael. This would leave comparatively large pieces which would then be **ground**. However some **milling** processes produce very fine particles directly; passing grain through a pair of millstones for example is **milling** but it is also **grinding** and can produce very fine flour.

Comment: @BoldBen - Thank you for clarifying that--I was thinking something similar, so it's good to have your insights.

Answer (score 2):

One verb refers to the action involved, the other refers to the product produced.

*Pulver* is the German word for 'powder' (as in gunpowder, for instance), so the causative verb *pulverize* simply means 'make powder (of); cause to become powder'.

*Grind*, on the other hand, is an old Germanic root referring to repetitive two-dimensional friction, i.e, rubbing hard things together, a human activity that produces powder; and one that goes back to various -lithic cultures.

*Grind* so old that there are other words starting with GR- that refer to two-dimensional friction of one kind or another: *graze grit grate grist grizzle grout*. That's one minor phonosemantic category of [the `GR-` assonance](https://websites.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/gr.pdf). There are others; the "vocal aggression" sense (e.g, *gruff grumble groan grump grunt grimace grouch growl grim gripe*) may be related to the low-frequency noises created by grinding and grating.

It is common with phonesthemes to have one sense for an activity, with additional sense for the noises the activity makes. For instance [the `KL-` assonance](https://websites.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/KL-chart.pdf) refers to impacts of one object on another (*clap clash clobber club clout*) as well as the sounds made by such impacts (*click clack clunk clang*).

Answer (score 0):

As [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pulverize?q=pulverising) says.

Pulverizing is pressing or crushing something until it becomes powder or a soft mass.

Grinding is making something into small pieces or a powder by pressing between hard surfaces.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: They also have another definition of grind: "to rub something against a hard surface, in order to make it sharper or smoother"